# Autoconf check for tar supporting xz

Tags: autoconf

I am preparing a new version of my [BSD Make scripts](https://bitbucket.org/michipili/bsdmakepscripts) and need to check if the `tar` command on the system supports the `-J` option for compression with `xz`.

What is the correct way of doing this in `autoconf`?  It does not seem that `AC_CHECK_PROG` allows to test a program with options.

In my case, a valid test could be `tar -cJf /dev/null /dev/null`, so I came up with the test

```
define([CHECK_TAR_OPTION], dnl
 [printf 'checking whether tar -$1 works...']
 [if tar c$1f /dev/null /dev/null >&- 2>&-;then $2=yes; else $2=no; fi]
 [printf '%s\n' "$$2"])dnl
```

In my code

```
 CHECK_TAR_OPTION(z,USE_GZIP)
```

will then set USE_GZIP to yes if `tar -z` works or to no otherwise.

I have some experience with M4 programming but not in relation with `autoconf` so I would appreciate a more idiosyncratic solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach seems to me the wrong way around.  You can always:

```
tar c /dev/null | <compression command> > foo.tar.<compression extension>
```

no matter what `tar` supports, which is pretty easy to do with `AC_CHECK_PROG` or whatever.  What seems to be important to you is what `tar` can *extract*, which you aren't testing.  This code walks through your compression methods and should select one based on the ability to round trip data through `tar`.

```
compressor_test ()
{
  AS_CASE(["$1"], [*xz], [tflag="J"], [*bzip2], [tflag="j"], [*gzip], [tflag="z"], [tflag=""])
  tar c /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 | "$1" | tar "tv${tflag}" > /dev/null 2>&1
  test $? -eq 0
}

AC_CACHE_CHECK([for a suitable tar compressor], [ac_cv_path_COMPRESSOR],
        [AC_PATH_PROGS_FEATURE_CHECK([COMPRESSOR], [xz bzip2 gzip cat],
          [[compressor_test $ac_path_COMPRESSOR \
            && ac_cv_path_COMPRESSOR=$ac_path_COMPRESSOR ac_path_COMPRESSOR_found=:]])])
AC_SUBST([COMPRESSOR], [$ac_cv_path_COMPRESSOR])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I am actually interest in creating the archive rather than reading them, nevertheless your answer is very useful and displays interesting features.

Comment: Moving this in my `aclocal.m4` results in the function `compressor_test` being diverted away.  What is the appropriate way to fix this?